# Wordpress center Footer Widgets

Tags: wordpress, widget, center, footer

I have a WordPress  4.9.4 site, which is [this](http://formacaodmsti.pt). The footer widgets are align to the left, as [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfi1e.png), 
I would like to make it so the footer widgets are centered. Where do I edit? I tried to edit the footer.php, and added:

```
.footer-sidebar {
                    text-align: center;

            }
```

Below this

```
 <?php $current_options = wp_parse_args(  get_option( 'busiprof_theme_options', array() ), theme_setup_data() ); ?>
    <!-- Footer Section -->
    <footer class="footer-sidebar"> 
        <!-- Footer Widgets -->
```

But it didn't change anything. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: give the admin footer widgets screen short

Comment: I think your footer widgets is 4 column

Comment: @KGR, is this what you're talking about? http://prntscr.com/ixy6y5

Comment: i ask this http://www.3waves.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/640px-designwidget.png

Comment: @KGR here it is http://prntscr.com/ixyeyn

Comment: you add the widgets in widgets option or theme option